Does anyone know the history of the SBM-20 Geiger Tube?

I know they were manufactured by the Soviets, but anything more than that I'm unsure of. I really want to know who originally designed the tube and what companies manufactured it and  where it was made/what machines were used/ how they were made. I was able to find these datasheets, but ran through an online translator I didn't get much back.  If anyone knows Russian, I'd be appreciative of any info you can get from them.
I don't know what SBM stands for, if you know please let me know.

Are you an historian? I designed my first Geiger counter when I was a teenager and bought my Geiger tube directly from the physicist who designed it (his home address after he and I talked a little on the phone.) Of the things you mention, I only knew who originally designed the tube. But not the rest. For design purposes, while that discussion helped me move more directly to a successful design, it certainly wasn't necessary. So is this more of an historical question and not so much about design? Not criticizing, just curious.

If you are asking question relating to the "design" specs then this is on topic, but if you want details of who, where, when, who sells it etc then those are off-topic.

@periblepsis I'm not a historian, I'm just thinking about designing my own Geiger Tube similar to that of the SBM-20. To do this it would be helpful to know more about it's genesis and Geiger tube design and manufacturing in general.
